# Having trouble setting up a user input based array for latest project

Tags: c#, arrays

Currently learning C# and having trouble getting started on next project...

I have this mess: //I don't know array length so trying to use char to exit loop for array...(if possible)

```
//Don't know when compiled how many workers
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    char response;

    string[] workerName = new string[MAX_LIST_VALUE]; //100
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < workerName.Length; i++)
    {
        Write("Do You Want To Enter A Worker's Name? Y or N: ");
        response = Convert.ToChar(ReadLine());
        if (response == 'Y' || response == 'y')
            Write("Please Enter The Worker's Name: ");
        if (response == 'N' || response == 'n')
        {
            workerName[i] = ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `Convert.ToChar`, try `Readline().Substring(0,1)`

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 0):

if using char is not absolutely important, you can try using string

```
void Main()
{
    string response;

            string[] workerName = new string[2]; //100
            for (int i = 0; i < workerName.Length; i++)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Do You Want To Enter A Worker's Name? Y or N: ");
            response = Console.ReadLine().Substring(0,1).ToLower();
            if (response == "y"){
                Console.WriteLine("Please Enter The Worker's Name: ");
                workerName[i] = Console.ReadLine();
                }
            else continue;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Worker Names entered are: ");
        for(int i = 0; i< workerName.Length; i++) {
            Console.WriteLine(workerName[i]);
        }
}
```

Hope this helps :) The code is self explanatory, let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: yes that helped with a lot of my questions                                                                    A program that first initializes arrays via user input with the names and wages of all employees, then prompts the user for the hours worked for each employee and computes their regular pay, overtime pay, gross income, federal tax deduction (10% of gross), state tax deduction (5% of gross), and net income. After the last employee is processed, the program displays totals for regular pay and overtime pay and the names and gross incomes for the employees that earned the most and least.

Comment: That's my current project (if your interested) I should be able to handle the rest maybe not the "most and least" because cannot use any built in array methods.... Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] workerName = new string[100];
        var i = 0;

        do
        {
            Console.Write("Please Enter The Worker's Name: ");
            workerName[i++] = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("Do You Want To Enter A Worker's Name? Y or N: ");

        } while (Console.ReadKey().Key == ConsoleKey.Y);
    }
```

But perhaps use a collection like List? Array is really for when you know how many elements in advance.

Likewise a For loop is intended for when you know how many times you are going to loop in advance. So use a Do loop for this problem.

There are so many ways to rewrite the logic to exit. I've offered a simple key press but the take-home from my answer is use the Do loop :)

Comment: yes a list would be simpler imo as well however I am unable to use them in current project... Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Use the `break` keyword to exit a loop early. I added a couple other comments:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    char response;

    string[] workerName = new string[MAX_LIST_VALUE]; //100
    int i;
    // No need to check the length, you already know that
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_LIST_VALUE; i++)
    {
        Write("Do You Want To Enter A Worker's Name? Y or N: ");
        response = Convert.ToChar(ReadLine());
        if (response == 'Y' || response == 'y')
        {
            Write("Please Enter The Worker's Name: ");
            workerName[i] = ReadLine();
        }
        // This is an alternative condition so use 'else if' 
        else if (response == 'N' || response == 'n')
        {
            // exit for loop
            break;
        }
    }
}
```